# Fetching values from an array in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have built an array, 
when I add it to watch

```
dict.Items
```

It returns

```
Expression                    Values
dict.Items                  
--dict.Items(0)                "value in it"
--dict.Items(1)                "value in it"
--dict.Items(2)                "value in it"
```

But when I try to add watch to expression

```
dict.Items(0)
```

It returns the following

```
Watch :   : dict.keys(0) : <Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object> : Variant/Empty : VBAProject.basMigration.UniqueReport
```

[image]

Comment: `Items` doesn't take an index.

Comment: I should probably elaborate: `Items` simply returns the whole array, so you'd need to watch: `Items()(0)` rather than `Items(0)`

Comment: it works :) 
You can add it as answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items` method doesn't take an index - it only returns the whole array, so you'd need to add a watch for `Items()(0)` rather than `Items(0)`